# AWS: Terraform file Upload / Execute Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to upload the file (.zip and .exe) and execute PowerShell commands on the ec2 instances while building it using terraform.

I have a base image (server 2012) where I am making all the changes using terraform. All instances are connected to the internal AWS network.

I tried "*data "template_file" "userdata*" it is only working with sysprep AMI and not working with the normal AMI which is not built using sysprep.

Also, all the instances are not exposed to the internet hence, I cannot use terraform remote_exec or other solutions which require internet. I can't expose them.

I tried many solutions but nothing working. Currently i am running commands on sysprep instance as shown below:

```
data "template_file" "userdata" {
  template = "<powershell>${file("setup.ps1")}</powershell><persist>false</persist>"
}
```

In the script, I am running PSSession commands to make changes to the instances.

Comment: Normally you would use `user_data`. Its not clear what is your actual issue. Can you clarify?

Comment: I am running ActiveDirectory machines and building the client machine (Joining domain, some configurations, etc). Now, for some machines, I have to upload the executable, zip files and want to run commands. So, I am really not sure how to upload a file using terraform where the instance is not exposed to the internet connection. Also, i am not able to execute commands through user_data. 

Problem: 

1. How to upload files using terraform?
2. How to run commands on the non-sysprep images.

Comment: user-data [can contain files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html). Or you can have Terraform [upload the file to an S3 bucket](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object), and then have your user-data script download the file from S3.